# Powershell paste data into existing sheet

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, com, excel-interop

I have a script that takes data from an existing .csv file and copies into an existing workbook (xlsx).

The problem: It always creates a new sheet in the workbook.

I would like to add the data to my current sheet and start at `A5` instead of    the top. Here is what I have

```
$source = 'C:\Scripts\monthly.csv' # source's fullpath 
$target = 'C:\Scripts\template.xlsx' # destination's fullpath 
$xl = new-object -com excel.application # creates Excel COM object in powershell
$xl.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user 
$wb2 = $xl.workbooks.open($source, $null, $true) # open source, readonly 
$wb1 = $xl.workbooks.open($target) # open target 
$sh1_wb1 = $wb1.sheets.item('triarqnew') # sheet in destination workbook 
$sheetToCopy = $wb2.sheets.item('monthly') # source sheet to copy 
$sheetToCopy.copy($sh1_wb1) # copy source sheet to destination workbook 
$wb2.close($false) # close source workbook w/o saving 
$wb1.SaveAs("C:\scripts\Report.xlsx") # close and save destination workbook 
$xl.quit()
```

Comment: using `$cell.item(1,1)=<value>` for specific cells so (not tested) try `$sheetToCopy.cells.item(1,5).copy($sh1_wb1)`

Comment: Says copy method of range class failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like that with `Copy()` and `PasteSpecial()`

```
$source = 'C:\Scripts\monthly.csv' # source's fullpath 
$target = 'C:\Scripts\template.xlsx' # destination's fullpath
$xl = new-object -com excel.application # creates Excel COM object in powershell
$xl.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user 
$wb2 = $xl.workbooks.open($source, $null, $true) # open source, readonly 
$wb1 = $xl.workbooks.open($target) # open target 
$sh1_wb1 = $wb1.sheets.item('triarqnew') # sheet in destination workbook 
$sheetToCopy = $wb2.sheets.item('monthly') # source sheet to copy 

# New code
$sheetToCopy.UsedRange.Copy()
$sh1_wb1.Range("A5").PasteSpecial()

$wb2.close($false) # close source workbook w/o saving 
$wb1.SaveAs("C:\scripts\Report.xlsx") # close and save destination workbook 
$xl.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! i tried this and get a "script failed due to call depth overflow. Not sure where to even start with that.

Comment: I tested it on may machine and it worked - there is also no risk of any recursion in that simple script so I guess your issue is somewhere else. Did you get the error while trying 'exactly' the script above or do you have other stuff around it?

Comment: Here is what the entire code looks like, nothing around it. Using W2012R2

Comment: Guess i cant paste it again

Comment: I forgot to add - Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel